# How to test restart() method from Stopwatch class?

Tags: c++

I want to test restart() method from Stopwatch class, a part of class looks like this:

```
class Stopwatch {
public:
    Stopwatch();
    void start();
    void restart(); // stopwatch reset and start
    ...
    uint64_t getTime() const; // gets the running time of the stopwatch in nanoseconds

private:
    ...
};
```

How to catch the time that was reset to 0 after restart()? I'm sure there must be a simpler way like sleep from unistd.h

Comment: Get the current time just before and after the call to `restart` and compare?

Comment: If I had made Stopwatch, I'd use dependency injection to pass in a timing service, and then for my unit tests I'd created a mock timing service and use that to ensure my unit tests for Stopwatch are deterministic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used "Some programmer dude" solution